# android bluetooth LE, how to get RR interval

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'm developing an android application uses bluetooth LE, i need to get RR interval. I start form this example on android developer site:

```
private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    // This is special handling for the Heart Rate Measurement profile. Data
    // parsing is carried out as per profile specifications.
    if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
        int format = -1;
        if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
        } else {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
        }
        final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, String.valueOf(heartRate));
    } else {
        // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
        final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
            for(byte byteChar : data)
                stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" +
                    stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

How i can get RR interval? I just do it with iOS, but on java i don't know how to do..

this is my code on iOS, and works perfectly:

```
- (void) updateWithHRMData:(NSData *)datas {

    const uint8_t *reportData = [datas bytes];

    uint16_t bpm = 0;
    uint16_t bpm2 = 0;

    if ((reportData[0] & 0x04) == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"Data are not present");
    }
    else
    {

        bpm = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(*(uint16_t *)(&reportData[2]));

        bpm2 = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(*(uint16_t *)(&reportData[4]));

        if (bpm != 0 || bpm2 != 0) {

            self.deviceReady = true;
            [lblNofascia setAlpha:0.0];
            [btnMonitor setAlpha:1.0];

            if (isRunning) {
                [self.elencoBattiti addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", bpm]];
                NSLog(@"%u", bpm);

                if (bpm2 != 0) {
                    [self.elencoBattiti addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", bpm2]];
                    NSLog(@"%u", bpm2);
                }

            }

        } else {

            if (isRunning) {
                totErrori++;

                NSLog(@"Dato non trasmesso");

                if (totErrori > 5) {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attenzione" message:@"Ho perso la connettività con la fascia. Ripetere la misurazione" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Continua", nil];
                    [alert show];

                    [self stopRunning];
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

thank you

Answer (score 4):

I have the following.

```
    if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        int flag = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
        int format = -1;
        int energy = -1;
        int offset = 1;
        int rr_count = 0;
        if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            Logger.trace("Heart rate format UINT16.");
            offset = 3;
        } else {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
            Logger.trace("Heart rate format UINT8.");
            offset = 2;
        }
        final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
        Logger.trace("Received heart rate: {}", heartRate);
        if ((flag & 0x08) != 0) {
            // calories present
            energy = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16, offset);
            offset += 2;
            Logger.trace("Received energy: {}", energy);
        }
        if ((flag & 0x10) != 0){
            // RR stuff.
            rr_count = ((characteristic.getValue()).length - offset) / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < rr_count; i++){
                mRr_values[i] = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16, offset);
                offset += 2;
                Logger.trace("Received RR: {}", mRr_values[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ifor. With some fixes the android code should work. The bit mask for RR data flag should be 16 according to specs and the array should be declared:

```
   if ((flag & 0x16) != 0){
        // RR stuff.
        rr_count = ((characteristic.getValue()).length - offset) / 2;
        Integer[] mRr_values = new Integer[rr_count];
        for (int i = 0; i < rr_count; i++){
            mRr_values[i] = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16, offset);
            offset += 2;
            Logger.trace("Received RR: {}", mRr_values[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 16 is 0x10 in hex.  Masking with 0x16 your actually matching 3 different bits which is wrong.  Best to do a bit of reading up on hex format...